# How to change the Release date in APPSTORE

Tags: iphone

HI All,
        I have submitted an ipad app in the app store.Its status changed as ready for sale.But i gave the release date 10 days more.So is there any option to change the release date.Please help me in this

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: This question doesn't belong to SO

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can change the *availability date* of your app in the "**Rights and pricing**" section of iTunes Connect (in "Manage your applications > YourApp").